# Какой формат телефона ищет данная regexp конструкция ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match('/^1\d{10,10}$/', $number)
```

Comment: А если ещё точнее, то с чего он должен начинаться, и далее 10 цифр это вроде понятно

Comment: Единица + 10 цифр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Американский. 11 цифр подряд без плюса, начинается с 1.

PS: http://www.hella.ru/code/codeworld.htm

Answer (score 1):

Этому регулярному выражению соответствует строка длиной ровно 11 символов, первый из которых `'1'`, а остальные десять - любые цифры.

[Проверить](https://regex101.com/r/GoDbPN/1)